# Do we need both "history" and "language-evolution"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Before writing this question, there were 14 questions using [history](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) and 7 questions using [language-evolution](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution).

Do we need both the tags? To me, it seems that [history](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) includes [language-evolution](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution), since the history of a language is its evolution in the time. Between the two, I would prefer [language-evolution](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution) to avoid the tag is used when the question asks about historical reasons, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although arguably [language-evolution](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution) is a subset of [history](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), I don’t think the reverse is always true and merging them all into [language-evolution](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution) would be a mistake. For example “What is the origin of the Esperanto green star?” is not about language evolution but it does have the history tag. There could also be interesting questions about the persecution of Esperanto during the wars which would be nice for the history tag.

I would be in favour of just keeping the two tags as they are.

Answer (score 0):

- Rename/Deplace [history](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) since it is unclear; I thought it was about historical facts about Esperantujo. If we have to keep it, I suggest [language-history](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-history)
- Keep [language-evolution](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution). The history of Esperanto is not only its evolution. Many words appeared in an artificial way before the language "evolved".
- I would be for replacing [history](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) with [language-origin](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-origin) (the origin of the choices of Zamenhof ktp) or [language-evolution](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution) whenever possible.